# PYQT5 :slot function is not working without lambda

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am working on application development using PYQT5.Now i am stuck at a point and finding out reason why application behaving weird.

> Code is working when slot function called using lambda function.On Clicking Browse , file navigator appears.
>   Below is code snippet:

```
class Main(QWidget,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self,MainWindow):
        super().__init__()
        self.__MainWindow = MainWindow
        self.__filename = None
        self.__imagepath = Main.imagePath()
        self.setupUi(MainWindow,self.__imagepath)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect( lambda :self.fileBrowser())
        self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(lambda :self.folderSelector())
        self.checkBox.toggled.connect(lambda :self.relativeFolder())
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda : self.mdftocsvConverter())
    def fileBrowser(self):
        self.__filename,filetype = 
        QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,"Open", "","MDF Files 
        (*.py)")
        if self.__filename :
           for file in self.__filename:
             self.lineEdit.setText( os.path.dirname(str(file)))
             break
```

> **Same code is called without lambda function** > clicking on browse button file navigator is not appearing.

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.fileBrowser)
```

I couldn't figure out the reason behind it.

> As per suggestion updated code link :[Main Code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fqhcod53qv3t81i/AAAZY9rdcY4eMkHQiDtufCUDa?dl=0)

Comment: The code shown in your question works the exactly same with or without the `lambda`.

Comment: PS: please do not link to code that is hidden inside a compressed archive.

Comment: @ekhumoro ok ,will takecare of it.

Comment: @ekhumoro it work three or four times after that it stop working.After running lambda code don't forget to clear pyc and clear all the variables of ide.

Comment: @ekhumoro shared unzip code ,updated code and removed lambda function.Now  Browse push button not working

Comment: It also works if connects are located in different places (for example, in a separate method, which is called from *main()*)

Comment: @Lalitkumar I would guess that the problem is caused by whatever ide you are using. If you run the code from a standard console, it should work as expected.